# Duda con load(1)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo la duda de que significara este "load(1)" en esta input

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="q" placeholder="Código o nombre del producto" onkeyup='load(1);'>
```

Según veo en el archivo hay otros load(1) al igual que aquí pero en ningún caso veo que la función load por ninguna parte. ¿Podría ser esto parte de JQuery?

Comment: revisa los archivos importados en el html

Answer (score 2):

Significa que el evento [`keyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeyup) está llamando una función `load()` que está declarada en alguno de los scripts de tu página. Si no existiese dicha función, debe levantar un `ReferenceError: load is not defined`.